# Is it possible to remove an A320's main gear using one main jack and one nose jack?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, landing-gear, airbus-a320

I have only one set of jacks (nose-main LH and RH) and I need to swap the main landing gear from one aircraft to another. I don't have a dummy landing gear. Is this possible?

Comment: Please do not shout in the title or in the post. It will get you attention but not the type you're hoping for.

Comment: I suspect that if you need to ask the question you shouldn't be doing the job.

Comment: This is the type of question that you should be asking to Airbus directly.  I'm sure they have some product support people that can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

If the maintenance manual says to use two main gear jacks, then use two main gear jacks. Using anything other than that makes you liable for any injuries or damage to equipment. Don’t let your lead push you around. Tell him to pound salt or get you another jack. Guys who cave to pressure like this make it tough for every other mechanic in the world who try to do things right. All we hear the rest of our careers are from guys who did things wrong and say, “Well, at ‘X’ airlines we didn’t have problems doing it this way.”

Furthermore, by not doing it right this time, you set the precedent to do everything else wrong every time. It’s like blackmail. “Boss, I don’t feel comfortable changing the engine with a 2x4 and a fishing pole.” Their response? “Remember when you did the lopsided gear change? You didn’t have any problems then, did you?”

Do it right or go find a job where shoddy workmanship won’t get people killed.

Comment: His title is misleading.  He means one set of jacks.  His problem is he needs to have two aircraft jacked at the same time.  Any solution would be a lot more hassle than simply renting a second set of jacks.  My guess is that this is a college student fishing for an answer after a beer bet.

Comment: Negative. This sort of thing happens all the time in “the real world.” Contract maintenance vendors are notorious for having only a partial amount of equipment or the absolute bare minimum. This is probably some lone mechanic or small group of mechanics in some remote contract maintenance station who are trying to skirt the books. It’s bad business all around because “getting the job done,” albeit incorrectly, is what keeps those 3rd party vendors open, makes it cheap for airlines, and costs real A&P jobs. IMO, it jeopardizes air safety. So the only real answer is to follow the book.